# React MUI TextField component with 'sx' works but 'styled' does not, why

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am writing a styled 'modal' TextField component which I want to overlay on my app. If I use 'sx' styling the component works as expected. However, if I use 'styled' from the mui material styles package (which I have used very successfully in the past) the component does not work correctly (after each keypress I lose focus and the component draws weirdly). Here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
    Box,
    IconButton,
    Modal,
    TextField
} from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CheckIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Check'
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear'

export default function TextFieldModal(props) {
    const {
        nameRect,
        initialValue,
        handleModalClose
    } = props;
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(true);
    const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(initialValue);

    const ClearButton = () => (
        <IconButton onClick={cancelEdit} style={{ color: 'red'}}>
            <ClearIcon />
        </IconButton>
    );

    const CheckButton = () => (
        <IconButton onClick={saveNewName} style={{ color: 'green'}}>
            <CheckIcon />
        </IconButton>
    );

    const cancelEdit = () => {
        closeModal(null);
    };

    const saveNewName = () => {
        closeModal(textValue);
    };

    const closeModal = (newName) => {
        setOpenModal(false);
        console.log('closing value = ', textValue);
        handleModalClose(newName);
    };

    const ModalTextField = styled(TextField)({
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: `calc(${nameRect.width}px - 2px)`,
        height: `calc(${nameRect.height}px - 2px)`,
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            borderRadius: '0rem',
            height: 'inherit',
            paddingRight: '0.25rem',
            fontSize: '0.875rem',
        }
    });

    return (
        <Modal
            open={openModal}
        >
            <Box sx={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: `${nameRect.top}px`,
                left: `${nameRect.left}px`,
                width: `calc(${nameRect.width}px - 2px)`,
                height: `calc(${nameRect.height}px - 2px)`
            }}>
                {/* <TextField
                    sx={{
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                        width: `calc(${nameRect.width}px - 2px)`,
                        height: `calc(${nameRect.height}px - 2px)`,
                        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
                            borderRadius: '0rem',
                            height: 'inherit',
                            paddingRight: '0.25rem',
                            fontSize: '0.875rem',
                        },
                    }}
                    */}
                <ModalTextField
                    id='modal-textfield'
                    key='modal-textfield'
                    value={textValue}
                    onChange={(event) => setTextValue(event.target.value)}
                    InputProps={{
                        endAdornment:
                            <>
                                <CheckButton />
                                <ClearButton />
                            </>
                    }}
                />
            </Box>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Using the 'sx' styled TextField gives the following result...key presses work find the name is changed.
[image]

Using the 'styled' component ModalTextField gives the following result...first keypress looks like it loses focus and no other keypresses can be done until clicking in the area again.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your const for the styled component outside you container and export it so you have access to it. Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-mzu5nt?file=/demo.tsx:2168-2528)

```
export const ModalTextField = styled(TextField)({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  width: `calc(${nameRect.width}px - 2px)`,
  height: `calc(${nameRect.height}px - 2px)`,
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      borderRadius: '0rem',
      height: 'inherit',
      paddingRight: '0.25rem',
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
  }
});

    export default function TextFieldModal(props) {
        const {
            nameRect,
            initialValue,
            handleModalClose
        } = props;
        const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(true);
        const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(initialValue);

.....

<ModalTextField
  id='modal-textfield'
  key='modal-textfield'
  value={textValue}
  onChange={(event) => setTextValue(event.target.value)}
    InputProps={{
     endAdornment:
       <>
        <CheckButton />
        <ClearButton />
       </>
       }}
      />
```

....

Comment: Thanks Akis, this was indeed correct. However, the sandbox didn't work for me because 'nameRect' is undefined. While playing around I found I can just use 'inherit' for the width and height anyways.